# Upload file with swaggerize-hapi and node.js?

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, swagger-2.0

I am creating an API endpoint with POST verb and it takes a file. I declared my endpoint as following:

```
    consumes:
  - application/json
  - multipart/form-data
   # format of the responses to the client (Accepts)
    produces:
    - application/json   
...
    /importfile:
        x-swagger-router-controller: import_file
        post:
          description: Sends the uploaded file to deliveries microservice to be processed.
          consumes:
            - multipart/form-data
          produces:
            - application/json
          operationId: importcsv
          parameters:
            - name: file
              in: formData
              description: file to upload
              required: true
              type: file
```

and I have the following in the import_file.js

```
const util = require('util');

function importcsv(req, res) {
    console.log(req);
    const message = util.format('hi there!');
    // this sends back a JSON response which is a single string
    return res.json(message);

}

module.exports = {
    importcsv,
};
```

Couple of questions:

1. The log in the router controller is never printed. It makes me think that this function is not being called. What is wrong?
2. Even though a success response returns I see this:

   HTTP/1.1

   content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
   cache-control: no-cache

   Multipart: Boundary not found

Why is that?

I'm new to Swagger. Thanks in advance.

Comment: res.json doesn't look right, how are you declaring the route config the handler is associated with?

Answer (score -1):

This post [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/pull/1141) made me think the Boundary issue was fixed. Well it is fixed and merged to the master branch on Dec 29, 2016 but the latest release of Swagger ([see](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/releases)) was made on  Dec 27, 2016.

So, the file upload doesn't work through Swagger at the moment (v1.5.12). That answers both of my questions.

I wrote the following unit test to test my controller which works:

```
const describe = require('ava-spec').describe;
const request = require('supertest-as-promised');
const server = require('../../../../app');

describe('controllers', () => {
    describe('import_file', () => {
        describe('POST /importfile', (it) => {
            it('should accept a file parameter', async (t) => {
                const res = await request(server)
                    .post('/importfile')
                    .attach('file', 'test/data/A.csv' )
                    .expect(200);
                t.is(res.body, 'file uploaded');
            });
        });
    });
});
```